# Data between Partials and Parent View Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, partials

So I have a new.html.erb which contains the form for a new ad. This view renders a partial to upload images called _upload_control.html.erb. It contains <%= file_field_tag :fileupload %> and I'm trying to reference the uploaded in new.html.erb in order to get the file in the parent's controller. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: what? What does accessing partial data from the parent view (which doesnt make sense) have to do with accessing it from the controller?

Comment: well the controller has access to the params hash populated with data from a form. the partial im rendering in the form is used to upload multiple files for a different object, so its not using 'f.' so i need some way of passing the file to the parent view for me to access it through the params hash in the controller. does that make any sense?

Comment: no. a form gets submitted to a controller - whether that form is in a view or a partial is irrelevant. If a form includes a partial with fields in it, then when that form is submitted, those fields from the partial will be submitted too.

Comment: it would help to clarify some things if you were to post code for your new.html.erb, the partial in question, and maybe the controller

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment

`The partial i'm rendering in the form is used to upload multiple files for a different object, so its not using 'f'`

You should use `f(form builder)` and *need to pass your form builder in locals* so that your partial can be called with that particular form builder, something like:

```
<%= form_for resource1 do |f|  %>
  <%=  render :partial => 'upload_control', :locals => { :f => f }  %>
<% end %>

<%= form_for resource2 do |builder|  %>
  <%=  render :partial => 'upload_control', :locals => { :builder => f }  %>
<% end %>
```

and your partial `_upload_control.html.erb`

```
<%= f.file_field :fileupload %>
```